# Selecting all odd rows from 3 to 305

Tags: vba, excel

I have a task that sounded very simple but it's giving me some troubles. 
All I need to do is simply to make a multiple selection of all the odd rows from 3 to 305 (so selecting simultaneously the rows `3, 5, 7, 9, ... 303, 305`).

Recording a macro while doing a multiple selection of the rows `3` and `5`, I see the resulting code is the following:

```
Range("3:3,5:5").Select
```

Starting from the above, I've written the following:

```
Dim strRange As String, j As Integer
strRange = "3:3,"
For j = 5 To 303 Step 2
   strRange = strRange & j & ":" & j & ","
Next j
strRange = strRange + "305:305"
```

The above `strRange` will result in the following:

```
Debug.Print strRange
>>> 3:3,5:5,7:7,9:9,11:11,13:13,15:15,17:17,19:19,21:21,23:23,25:25,27:27,29:29,31:31,33:33,35:35,37:37,39:39,41:41,43:43,45:45,47:47,49:49,51:51,53:53,55:55,57:57,59:59,61:61,63:63,65:65,67:67,69:69,71:71,73:73,75:75,77:77,79:79,81:81,83:83,85:85,87:87,89:89,91:91,93:93,95:95,97:97,99:99,101:101,103:103,105:105,107:107,109:109,111:111,113:113,115:115,117:117,119:119,121:121,123:123,125:125,127:127,129:129,131:131,133:133,135:135,137:137,139:139,141:141,143:143,145:145,147:147,149:149,151:151,153:153,155:155,157:157,159:159,161:161,163:163,165:165,167:167,169:169,171:171,173:173,175:175,177:177,179:179,181:181,183:183,185:185,187:187,189:189,191:191,193:193,195:195,197:197,199:199,201:201,203:203,205:205,207:207,209:209,211:211,213:213,215:215,217:217,219:219,221:221,223:223,225:225,227:227,229:229,231:231,233:233,235:235,237:237,239:239,241:241,243:243,245:245,247:247,249:249,251:251,253:253,255:255,257:257,259:259,261:261,263:263,265:265,267:267,269:269,271:271,273:273,275:275,277:277,279:279,281:281,283:283,285:285,287:287,289:289,291:291,293:293,295:295,297:297,299:299,301:301,303:303,305:305
```

... which looks correct. However, when I try to do this:

```
Range(strRange).Select '<-- Note: workbook and worksheet are correctly referenced
```

... I get a `Run-time error 1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed.`
Why is this happening? Is there a maximum length of the string I can pass to the `Range` class that I cannot find on the web? How would I go to make this multiple selection if so?

Comment: Yes, there is a limit, I forget how much, but looks like you've exceeded it. GS has the answer.

Comment: @DougGlancy yes, it looks like. but I cannot find it anyhwere in the doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub OddPicker()
   Dim rng As Range, i As Long

   For i = 3 To 305 Step 2
      If rng Is Nothing Then
         Set rng = Cells(i, 1)
      Else
         Set rng = Union(rng, Cells(i, 1))
      End If
   Next i

   rng.EntireRow.Select
End Sub
```

I can't find the string limit to *Range()*; I looked here:

[Excel Specifications and Limits](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)

**EDIT#1:**

I ran this:

```
Sub flskdjfs()
   Dim strRange As String, j As Integer
   strRange = "3:3,"
   Dim r As Range
   On Error GoTo whatis

   For j = 5 To 303 Step 2
      strRange = strRange & j & ":" & j & ","
      Set r = Range(Mid(strRange, 1, Len(strRange) - 1))
   Next j
   strRange = strRange + "305:305"

whatis:
   MsgBox j & vbCrLf & Len(strRange)
End Sub
```

and got this MsgBox result:

[image]

So I assume that after 256 characters *Range()* gets flakey.

Comment: Thank you, this answers the practical side of the question so I will gladly accept it. However, still... why does the method fail?

Comment: There is definitely a limit...............I  can't find official documentation for this limit..........but you can discover it through experimentation...........try **Set**ting a range inside your j-for loop and seeing where it dies...........